# Stop Access from Auto assigning Datatypes

Tags: ms-access, vba

First of all, I know the easiest thing to do is define a specification, however, I'd like to make this simple eliminated the need for a spec.

I'm using something as simple as

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "TempPayments", theSource, True
```

When I do this, I get my temp table and it has predefined datatypes. This is horrible because Microsfot seems to think the "USD" is a long int and not a double. They also assume the values for "Year", "Month", and "Day" are long ints.

I want everything to come in as "Short Text". Can I do this without using a spec?

Comment: If you first create `TempPayments` with all text fields, you can then use `TransferText` to import the data and the field types will remain text.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Really, there's nothing more to say. Just use an import specification.

Comment: Okay. Guess I'll use Specs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create your own temp table ahead of time with all text fields, plus an autonumber ID. Then import your file into that table with HasFieldNames = False. You can then delete the first row (the field names), validate/massage the data any way you like and then append it wherever it needs to go.
Edit: You'll need to name the fields in the temp table F1, F2, F3,...

Comment: If you use `HasFieldNames = False`, Access will assign its own names to the source fields, such as `F1` for the first field, etc.  So you will need to create matching field names in the destination table in order to avoid complaints like *"Field 'F1' doesn't exist in destination table ..."*.

Comment: You are correct. I typically use a temp table with field names F1, F2... That also allows me to check that the import file has the field names that are expected.